# Need to split data into multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in one column and I want to split it into multiple columns.
For example I have data like

```
123*4546.765,4653:342.324
```

I want to split this as `123` in a column, `4546` in a column, `765` in a column, `4653` in a column and so on ...

Comment: How are you thinking it could be done or how to do it.  I guess you'd have to use Range.TextToColumns method. Tab, Comma, Semi-colon and **one** other character per pass.  A non-trivial task in VBA so you could start by recording some macros then refining them in the IDE.  When you have some substantial code that isn't quite working then post a question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below (using the `RegEx`).

The `RegEx` pattern is looking for any consecutive 1 to 10 digits `.Pattern = "[0-9]{1,10}"`.

Then, if at least 1 Match found, loop inside all Matches and output them (from Cell "A1" and move one column to the right).

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractNumbers()

Dim Col As Long
Dim Reg1 As Object
Dim RegMatches As Variant
Dim Match As Variant

Set Reg1 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With Reg1
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "[0-9]{1,10}" ' Match any set of 9 digits
End With

Set RegMatches = Reg1.Execute("123*4546.765,4653:342.324") '<-- you can use a `Range` value instead of hard-code 

If RegMatches.Count >= 1 Then '<-- check that at least 1 match made with the RegEx
    Col = 1
    For Each Match In RegMatches
        MsgBox Match ' <-- output in msgbox
        Cells(1, Col).Value = Match '<-- output the numbers from Cell A1 and move one column to the right
        Col = Col + 1
    Next Match
End If

End Sub
```